# Problem with canvas using vega with nodejs (server side only)

Tags: node.js, server-side-rendering, vega, node-canvas

I've been working for a few weeks now on a Discord bot that basically compiles stats on the server and deduces patterns. In order to improve it, I wanted to make it generate graphs as PNGs in order to send them back to the user - in short, no DOM.
In order to achieve this, I'm currenlty using vega (version 5.10.1 - latest) and node-canvas (version 2.6.1 - latest), with nodejs v12.16.1.

I've been scouring the web for help on vega usage, and found a couple contradicting sources. I've been using the example code provided here :
https://vega.github.io/vega/usage/

The thing is that I keep getting this error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
message:"Cannot read property 'getContext' of null"
stack:"TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
    at resize (e:\DEV\GIT REPOS\GITHUB\PERSO\JS\test-StatBot\node_modules\vega-scenegraph\build\vega-scenegraph.js:3665:28)
    at CanvasRenderer.prototype$6.resize (e:\DEV\GIT REPOS\GITHUB\PERSO\JS\test-StatBot\node_modules\vega-scenegraph\build\vega-scenegraph.js:3714:5)
    at CanvasRenderer.prototype$4.initialize (e:\DEV\GIT REPOS\GITHUB\PERSO\JS\test-StatBot\node_modules\vega-scenegraph\build\vega-scenegraph.js:3294:17)
    at CanvasRenderer.prototype$6.initialize (e:\DEV\GIT REPOS\GITHUB\PERSO\JS\test-StatBot\node_modules\vega-scenegraph\build\vega-scenegraph.js:3709:28)
    at initializeRenderer (e:\DEV\GIT REPOS\GITHUB\PERSO\JS\test-StatBot\node_modules\vega-view\build\vega-view.js:657:8)
    at renderHeadless (e:\DEV\GIT REPOS\GITHUB\PERSO\JS\test-StatBot\node_modules\vega-view\build\vega-view.js:780:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async View.renderToCanvas [as toCanvas] (e:\DEV\GIT REPOS\GITHUB\P...
```

Here is the code which is giving me trouble :

```
// Imports
const vega = require('vega');


// Render image from given graph spec (statsObject)
async function graphToImage (statsObject) {

    graphObject = new vega.View(vega.parse(statsObject), { renderer: 'none'});

    const pngName = generateFileName(10);

    removeExistingFile(pngName);

    graphObject.toCanvas().then(canvas => {

        console.log('Writing PNG to file...');
        writeFile(`../../../../generated/${pngName}.png`, canvas.toBuffer());

    }).catch(err => {

        console.log("Error writing PNG to file:");
        console.error(err);

    });


    return pngName;
}
```

I don't really know how canvas or vega work, and so I have no idea what could be causing this issue and how to fix it... However, the problem seems to be located inside of the `toCanvas()` method. Any help is much appreciated !

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Using view.toSVG() along with the npm package sharp worked well for me 


const view = new vega.View(vega.parse(templateObject), {renderer: 'none'});

view.toSVG().then(async function (svg) {

    await sharp(Buffer.from(svg))
        .toFormat('png')
        .toFile('fileName.png')

}).catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! That's what I ended up going with too, but your code is way cleaner than mine...

Answer (score 1):

Edit : I managed to fix my issue, and I am posting the anwser here for future notice :

I succeeded to actually generate a graph picture by rendering the View object straight to an SVG string, by using `view.toSVG()` instead of the buggy `view.toCanvas()`, which worked great.

Then, all that was left to do was to convert the obtained SVG string into a PNG file, and that was it.

Here is the updated, working code :

```
// Imports
const vega = require('vega');


// Render image from given graph object
async function graphToImage (statsObject) {

    // Generate a new 10-char hex string
    const pngName = generateHexStringName(10);


    // Remove any existing file with the same name in order to prevent confusion
    removeExistingFile(pngName);


    var view = new vega.View(vega.parse(statsObject), {renderer: 'none'});


    // Generate an SVG string
    view.toSVG().then(async function (svg) {

        // Working SVG string
        console.log(svg);

        // Process obtained SVG string, e. g. write it to PNG file


    }).catch(function(err) {

        console.error(err);

    });


    // Return the name of the generated PNG file
    return pngName;
}
```